# Passing an NSArray to a segue, which passes it to another segue?

Tags: ios, tableview, segue

New to ios here, so please bear with me. I have a main view controller (mvc) which segues to a table view controller (tc1). 
When a row in tc1 is touched, it segues to (tc2) to display a second tableview:

```
+--------+     +--------+      +--------+
|        |     |        |      |        |
|  mvc   |---->|  tc1   |----->|   tc2  |
|        |     |        |      |        |
|        |     |        |      |        |
+--------+     +--------+      +--------+
```

Data for the tableview in tc1 is passed as an array in mvc's `prepareForSegue`. I am loading it into a property defined in tc1.h.

Since tc1 is initiating `prepareForSegue` for the tc2 tableview, it seems the only way to get tc2 populated is to pass two arrays to tc1; one for tc1 tableview and a second for tc1 to pass to tc2 in `prepareForSegue`. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the arrays you are using are part of some model. Make a separate model class hierarchy and possibly a DataAdapter (a class that will act as a context for your model). So when you present a controller, you can ask for data from the adapter, for example: `self.users= [[DataAdapter instance] allUsers];`.

In case the data you are passing is used to temporarely display something, or isn't part of a model, there is nothing wrong with passing it in prepareForSegue call.

Comment: Thanks. I just ended up doing it the latter way. It doesn't seem the most efficient but that's the way it is sometimes. The array data is all R/O which is being passed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider  using separate uiviewcontroller classes for both table 1 and 2. Assuming you are using storyboards, this means two viewcontrollers with tableviews nested within each view. Connect the viewcontrollers with segues and name them.

Declare the appropriate properties, remember to import headers, and you should be able to a.) use the prepareforsegue method you are familiar with, and b.) populate the table rows with the passed data.

Comment: Both tc1 and tc2 do indeed have separate TabeViewControllers. The problem is, tc1 is segue'd from the main ViewController and tc2 is segue'd from tc1's TableViewController. I think what you are suggesting would require tc1 to jump back to the main VC, and then issue prepareForSegue with a different TableViewControlller in order to load that TVC from main. I must be misunderstading because that seems like a less desirable solution that passing the tc2 data array along to tc1.